# Magento 2 captcha cannot show

Tags: magento2, captcha

I found :

> Cannot change permissions for path "/var/www/html/ pub/media/captcha/base" Warning!chmod(): Operation not permitted in support_report.log.

I have given `/var/www/html/ pub/media/captcha` permission 777 and ownership root.  But the problem still appears.

How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best security practices, the owner of the Magento filesystem should be one user, and the user that PHP or the webserver runs as a different user.

So for example, if you have a user "mySiteUser" and PHP runs as the user and group "www-data" (httpd or apache for RedHat/CentOS/Fedora); then your `/var/www/html/<site_name>/pub/media` would be owned by mySiteUser and the group would be "www-data": `chown -R mySiteUser:www-data /var/www/html/<site_name>/pub/media`.

That's not the only folder that should be set up like this.  There are others.  I suggest you read through the Magento DevDocs on file permissions for more info: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html